# Proving that $U(A) = U(A_1) \times \dots \times U(A_k).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Here is the question I want to solve:

Let $A_1, A_2, \dots ,A_k$ be rings. Then $U(A) = U(A_1) \times U(A_2) \times  \dots \times U(A_k)$ as groups under the component wise multiplication operation, where $U(A)$ is the group of units of $A$ and $U(A_i)$ is the group of units of $A_i, 1 \leq i \leq k.$

**My questions are:**

1- I think the equality should be isomorphism, right?

2- I do not know how to tackle this problem, should I define an isomorphism map? how can I do this?

Comment: You never say who $A$ *is*...  If it is the product of the $A_i$, then it is an equality, not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction, we can only think the case $k=2$.i.e. we show $U(A\times B)\cong U(A)\times U(B)$.

Now  canonical map $f:U(A\times B)\to U(A)\times U(B)$ defined by $f(a,b):=(a,b)$ is well-defined and bijective.

In fact, for $(a,b)\in U(A\times B)$ the inverse element $(c,d)$ is $c=a^{-1}\in A, d=b^{-1}\in B$.

Comment: What is the importance of the last line in the proof?

Comment: Key property is $U(A\times B)=\{(a,b)\in A\times B~|~ a\in U(A), b\in U(B)\}$. This is proven by taking elements.

Comment: If you don't understand my proof, I wii add my post.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: I am so sorry for this @Shaun

Comment: @Nakayama I still did not get what is the importance of showing the inverse element. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Nakayama why need induction? why just we define $f$ on $k$ components.

Comment: We don’t need induction.  But if we use induction, this case is more simple.

Comment: Do you understand logic of this proof？

Comment: Using the isomorphism symbol where you have an actual equality is bound to be confusing...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin the original statement had equality not isomorphism .... but I guessed it is a typo .... that is why I asked.